# Export components to all pages in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am quite new to SvelteKit (but have used Django before). I am trying to make a web app with DRF as the backend and Svelte as the frontend. I have started an app for the frontend, and have made a few pages.

There are some things I want to be shown in all pages (eg. header navigation and footer). For now, I've done that by adding the HTML to the app.html file.

For static HTML, this would probably work. However, I want to show some components on all the pages (eg. downtime alerts). How do I go about doing that? Hopefully if I figure this out, I can move the header and footer into seperate components as well, and follow the same technique for showing them in all pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `+layout.svelte` file. Basically, let's say we want to display an element on every page. So we add a `+layout.svelte` file to the **routes** directory.

The contents look something like this.

```html
<nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/settings">Settings</a>
</nav>

<slot />
```

The `<slot />` tag is the content of the page (i.e. `+page.svelte`). Anything around that is things like our navbar or footer.

This applies to every page in every subdirectory (and its corresponding subroute) of **routes** (the behaviour you were seeking).

For more information on `+layout.svelte`, consult [this page of the SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout).
For more on the whole routing thing, consult [this page](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing).

Comment: Extra note, you can also import and use Svelte components with the same method.

Comment: Thank you very much! This perfectly solves my question.